# How can I ingest user_age_bracket & gender metrics associated with ga_session_id in google analytics into big query?

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I am having trouble finding the user age bracket and gender metrics name associated with google analytics session id? Is that the correct name for the metrics? Because I want to ingest it into bigquery. I have turned on google data signals. I need to be able to attribute a ga session id with age bracket/ gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in BQ, I don't even think you can do this within the webui for privacy reasons. You can only look at it as a whole.

Comment: when i tried using supermetrics the dimension is there, user_age_bracket and gender and it can be tied to source, medium and campaign. So I am assuming that there's a way to tie that into the whole data.

Comment: Supermetrics is not the same as the BQ export. You can even look at the export schema into BQ, nothing includes this dimension. This is only available as part of the webui.